# Inserting my qt application to yocto image and runing it after startup

Tags: qt, yocto, imx6

I generated an image with "fsl-image-qt5-validation-imx" for i.MX 6SoloX SABRE Development Board. I can run the my application via Qt creator. However, I don't know how to insert this application to yocto image in order to run after startup and build it. Also, this application needs lots of library such as qtchart, qtserialport etc. How can I do this? Or is there any document for learning doing that? Thanks.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/QtForDeviceCreation/qtee-customization.html#booting-to-a-custom-application

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use RDEPENDS in your recipe to include the runtime dependencies directly. Use the DEPENDS keyword to tell the recipe which of those packages are needed to build your package. I'm assuming you can install your package to the image already.

Startup on target depends on what startup you use, init.d or systemd.

There are lots of documents.

http://www.embeddedlinux.org.cn/OEManual/update-rc-d_class.html
https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html

This should have been easy google.